# Should pluginManagement be used in submodules?

Tags: maven, pom.xml

I am reading sonatype's [tutorial](http://books.sonatype.com/mvnex-book/reference/multimodule-sect-simple-weather.html) on multimodule projects and I see that in submodule they use the `<pluginManagement>` configuration like this:

```
<build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
```

This confuses me as I thought that `<pluginManagement>` is to be used in parent POM to provide common plugin configuration for submodules. What are the reasons for using plugin managment in children poms ?

Comment: Simple answer No. In parent modules yes in childs no.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time `<pluginManagement>` is used in parent pom files.

It configures plugins. But makes them not active part of the build. Therefor you need to add them to the `<plugins>` part of the Maven pom file. Most not done in parent pom files, but done in the (sub) modules, using / refering to that (parent) pom.

Comment: You can't have a module which is packaging jar etc. which contains modules definition. That will produce a failure in Maven.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is special to the use of the surefire plugin.

Since you execute the plugin with `mvn test` the surefire plugin will be executed with the configuration specified in the `pluginManagement` block. Other plugins are not executed directly but by binding them to another lifecycle phase and thus must be specified in the `plugin` block.

See the [usage page](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/usage.html) of the surefire plugin.